# Filter Array Of Objects Based On Dictionary in React

Tags: javascript

I am new to UI stuff. I know how to do this c#. I have a dictionary named CarValues in my code which contains following data:

```
dictionary: CarValues

key ==> string

Value ==> Array

1. key => Honda,
   Value => white, yellow
2. Key => Volkswagen 
   Value => 123, 456
3. key => Mercedes
   Value => E, A, B
```

I have one more array with objects like below

Car Objects:

```
Cars = [
{
  Toyota: White
  Mercedes: B
  Honda: Red
  Volkswagen: 456
},
{
  Toyota: Green
  Mercedes: Z
  Honda: Blue
  Volkswagen: 234
},
{
  Toyota: Black
  Mercedes: A
  Honda: Yellow
  Volkswagen: 789
},
{
  Toyota: White
  Mercedes: B
  Honda: Red
  Volkswagen: 456
},
{
  Toyota: Green
  Mercedes: Z
  Honda: Blue
  Volkswagen: 234
},
{
  Toyota: Grey
  Mercedes: M
  Honda: Orange
  Volkswagen: 394
}
.............
.............
]
```

I want to filter out objects from Cars that matches Car Values.
Iterate through the keys of Cars and see if the values are present in Car Values.

```
The output should be something like below:

{
  Toyota: White
  Mercedes: B
  Honda: Red
  Volkswagen: 456
},
{
  Toyota: Black
  Mercedes: A
  Honda: Yellow
  Volkswagen: 789
}
```

I was doing something like

```
    var copyCars= [];

    Object.entries(this.state.carValues).forEach(function (key) {
        Object.entries(this.state.carValues[key]).forEach(function (value) {
            var filterData = this.state.cars.filter(x => x[key] == value);
            copyCars.push(filterData);
        })            
    });
```

But I am getting error at this line as of now saying this is undefined.
    var filterData = this.state.cars.filter(x => x[key] == value);

Comment: @ChrisG Please see my edit above. That is what I have done and tried different things. Since this was the last one, I added it above.

Comment: @Vicky Edit your question to contain actual JavaScript objects and we can help with the filtering part.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how actually you want to filter your array. But I think you can use `Array.filter` functionality for this. [MSDN (Array.filter)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Example:

```
/* let's assume, that you want to filter cars with 'Volkswagen' value to be in [456, 789];*/    

const volkswagenIds = [456, 789];
let filteredCars = Cars.filter(car => {
    return volkswagenIds.indexOf(car.Volkswagen) !== -1;
});
```